# is feature cross the same as an interaction term?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, interaction, terminology

Well, I am studying Machine Learning and I came up with the terminology 'feature crosses' which for me seems similar to an interaction term. Are they the same?

Comment: Naturally, we wouldn't be able to tell w/o you explaining what "feature crosses" means.

Comment: A feature cross is a synthetic feature formed by multiplying (crossing) two or more features. Crossing combinations of features can provide predictive abilities beyond what those features can provide individually.https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/feature-crosses/video-lecture

Comment: @gunes any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A feature cross is a synthetic feature formed by multiplying
> (crossing) two or more features. Crossing combinations of features can
> provide predictive abilities beyond what those features can provide
> individually.

Yes, this is exactly the same with feature interactions.

Comment: do you have any references or may reason how they are the same (interaction term = feature cross?

Comment: e.g. https://pycaret.org/feature-interaction/

Comment: ... or consult any of the (thousands) of posts here on CV discussing interactions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+interaction.

Comment: it is surely a better suggestion than mine.